# Precise conversion of 32-bit unsigned integer into a float in range (-1;1)

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, cuda, floating-point

According to [articles like this](https://lemire.me/blog/2017/02/28/how-many-floating-point-numbers-are-in-the-interval-01/), half of the floating-point numbers are in the interval [-1,1]. Could you suggest how to make use of this fact so to replace the naive conversion of a 32-bit unsigned integer into a floating-point number (while keeping the uniform distribution)?

Naive code:

```
uint32_t i = /* randomly generated */;
float f = (float)i / (1ui32<<31) - 1.0f;
```

The problem here is that first the number `i` is converted into `float` losing up to 8 lower bits of precision. Only then the number is scaled to [0;2) interval, and then to [-1;1) interval.

Please, suggest the solution in C or C++ for x86_64 CPU or CUDA if you know it.

Update: the solution with a `double` is good for x86_64, but is too slow in CUDA. Sorry I didn't expect such a response. Any ideas how to achieve this without using double-precision floating-point?

Comment: Maybe `float f = (float) ((double) i / (1ui32<<31) - 1.0);`?

Comment: Operation on a `double` would be too slow in CUDA. Sorry I didn't realize I should mention this in the question.

Comment: Most of the time, the precision you'd lose converting `i` to float you'll lose anyway.  Small values of `i` don't have enough precision to lose any.  You might lose one bit for sufficiently large values of `i` (that also have low bits set) due to rounding.

Comment: The performance of `double` is not limited by CUDA but by the GPU you are running on.  Some CUDA-capable GPUs have higher `double` throughput than any x86_64 CPU.  If you are interested in fastest possible performance, I would try to eliminate the floating-point division operation.  I think it should be possible.

Comment: @RobertCrovella, yes, that is what I meant. The floating-point division is easily replaced by multiplication, but the precision still gets lost in the same way, as I understand.

Comment: Take your 32-bit uniform signed integer.  Mask off the lower 8 bits.  The result is your 23-bit mantissa and sign bit of your `float` quantity  The exponent is trivial to calculate.

Comment: @RobertCrovella: The IEEE-754 basic 32-bit binary floating-point format has 24-bit significands, so removing eight bits wastes a bit.

Comment: I said mantissa not significand, but mask 7 bits if you think that makes sense. I dont think you're grasping my approach. The approach I'm suggesting is to make sure you cover the full space of the 23 bits of mantissa. For that you only need 23 uniformly distributed bits. I think that was the crux of the question. Then you handle sign bit and exponent separately. And yes you would need some special casing for 0. You dont have to generate the 24th significand bit. It is not represented and it is always one.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the calculation using `double` instead so you don't lose any precision on the `uint32_t` value, then assign the result to a `float`.

```
float f = (double)i / (1ui32<<31) - 1.0;
```

Comment: I think this will lose a lot of precision during the conversion ... as double has no reason to use denormalized version of result and the conversion to float most likely just cut off the mantissa bits ... resulting in  a lot of integer values mapped into the same value.... but that is just my guess and I might be wrong.

Comment: It is inevitable that multiple integer values get mapped into the same `float` result value, for the conversion requested by OP.  This method looks sound to me, apart from OP's objection to the use of `double`

Comment: @RobertCrovella I agree ... however mine approach is not mapping 2 int values to the same float and vice versa but at the cost of non-linearity and loosing 2 bits from the used int range... I know its not answering the OP problem directly but I taught it could get handy for someone ...

Answer (score 2):

In case you drop the uniform distribution constraint its doable on 32bit integer arithmetics alone:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
float i32_to_f32(int   x)
    {
    int exp;
    union _f32          // semi result
        {
        float f;        // 32bit floating point
        DWORD u;        // 32 bit uint
        } y;
    // edge cases
    if (x== 0x00000000) return  0.0f;
    if (x< -0x1FFFFFFF) return -1.0f;
    if (x> +0x1FFFFFFF) return +1.0f;
    // conversion
    y.u=0;                              // reset bits
    if (x<0){ y.u|=0x80000000; x=-x; }  // sign (31 bits left)
    exp=((x>>23)&63)-64;                // upper 6 bits -> exponent -1,...,-64 (not 7bits to avoid denormalized numbers)
    y.u|=(exp+127)<<23;                 // exponent bias and bit position
    y.u|=x&0x007FFFFF;                  // mantissa
    return y.f;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
int f32_to_i32(float x)
    {
    int exp,man,i;
    union _f32          // semi result
        {
        float f;        // 32bit floating point
        DWORD u;        // 32 bit uint
        } y;
    // edge cases
    if (x== 0.0f) return  0x00000000;
    if (x<=-1.0f) return -0x1FFFFFFF;
    if (x>=+1.0f) return +0x1FFFFFFF;
    // conversion
    y.f=x;
    exp=(y.u>>23)&255; exp-=127;        // exponent bias and bit position
    if (exp<-64) return 0.0f;
    man=y.u&0x007FFFFF;                 // mantissa
    i =(exp<<23)&0x1F800000;
    i|= man;
    if (y.u>=0x80000000) i=-i;          // sign
    return i;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I chose to use only 29 bits + sign = ~ 30 bits of integer to avoid denormalized numbers havoc which I am too lazy to encode (it would get you 30 or even 31 bits but much slower and complicated).

But the distribution is not linear nor uniform at all:

[image: linearity]

in Red is the `float` in range `<-1,+1>` and Blue is `integer` in range `<-1FFFFFFF,+1FFFFFFF>`.

On the other hand there is no rounding at all in both conversions ...

**PS.** I think there might be a way to somewhat linearize the result by using a precomputed **LUT** for the 6 bit exponent (64 values).

Answer (score 1):

The thing to realize is while `(float)i` does lose 8-bit of precision (so it has 24 bits of precision), the result only has 24 bits of precision as well. So this precision loss is not necessarily a bad thing (this is actually more complicated, because if `i` is smaller, it will lose less than 8-bits. But things will work out well).

So we just need to fix the range, so the originally non-negative value gets mapped to `INT_MIN..INT_MAX`.

This expression works: `(float)(int)(value^0x80000000)/0x80000000`.

Here's how it works:

1. The `(int)(value^0x80000000)` part flips the sign bit, so `0x0` gets mapped to `INT_MIN`, and `0xffffffff` gets mapped to `INT_MAX`.
2. Then there is conversion to `float`. This is where some rounding happens, and we lose precision (but it is not a problem).
3. Then just divide by `0x80000000` to get into the range `[-1..1]`. As this division just adjusts the exponent part, this division doesn't lose any precision.

So, there is only one rounding, the other operations doesn't lose precision. These chain of operations should have the same effect, as calculating the result in infinite precision, then doing the rounding to `float` (this theoretical rounding has the same effect as the rounding at the 2. step)

But, to be absolutely sure, I've verified with brute force checking all the 32-bit values that this expression results in the same value as `(float)((double)value/0x80000000-1.0)`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest (if yout want to avoid division and use an accurately float-representable start value of 1.0*2^-32):

```
float e = i * ldexp(1.0,-32) - 1.0;
```

Comment: `i * ldexp(1.0,-32)` is `ldexp(i, -32)` or `i * 0x1p-32f`. In C, it should be `ldexpf` to stick to `float`. Similarly, `1.0` should be `1.0f`.

Comment: However, accuracy is lost be converting to `float` before centering. OP might want that to some extent, but it might be preferable to subtract in integer, then multiply in `float`. But then there is an unsigned/signed issue doing the subtraction.

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas how to achieve this without using double-precision floating-point?

Without assuming too much about the insides of `float`:

Shift `u` until the most significant bit is set, halving the `float` conversion value.

"keeping the uniform distribution"

50% of the `uint32_t` values will be in the [0.5 ... 1.0)
25%  of the `uint32_t` values will be in the [0.25 ... 0.5)
12.5% of the `uint32_t` values will be in the [0.125 ... 0.25)
6.25% of the `uint32_t` values will be in the [0.0625 ... 0.125)
...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

float ui32to0to1(uint32_t u) {
  if (u) {
    float band = 1.0f/(1llu<<32);
    while ((u & 0x80000000) == 0) {
      u <<= 1;
      band *= 0.5f;
    }
    return (float)u * band;
  }
  return 0.0f;
}
```

Some test code to show functional equivalence to `double`.

```
int test(uint32_t u) {
  volatile float f0 = (float) ((double)u / (1llu<<32));
  volatile float f1 = ui32to0to1(u);
  if (f0 != f1) {
    printf("%8lX %.7e %.7e\n", (unsigned long) u, f0, f1);
    return 1;
  }
  return 0;
}

int main(void) {
  for (int i=0; i<100000000; i++) {
    test(rand()*65535u ^ rand());
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Various optimizations are possible, especially with assuming properties of `float`.  Yet for an initial answer, I'll stick to a general approach.

For improved efficiency, the loop needs only to iterate from 32 down to `FLT_MANT_DIG` which is usually 24.

```
float ui32to0to1(uint32_t u) {
  float band = 1.0f/(1llu<<32);
  for (int i = 32; (i>FLT_MANT_DIG && ((u & 0x80000000) == 0)); i--) {
    u <<= 1;
    band *= 0.5f;
  }
  return (float)u * band;
}
```

---

This answers maps [0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1] to [0.0 to 1.0)

To map to [0 to 2<sup>32</sup>-1] to (-1.0 to 1.0).  It can form -0.0.

```
if (u >= 0x80000000) {
  return ui32to0to1((u - 0x80000000)*2);
} else
  return -ui32to0to1((0x7FFFFFFF - u)*2);
}
```